# WordPress Header Async

Tags: wordpress, asynchronous

In my WordPress theme the "front-page.php" and "index.php" both get the same header file ("header.php") as the "about.php" however the "front" and "index" pages have the following header code:

```
<script async src="..."></script>
```

Though the "about" page has this code without the async:

```
<script src="..."></script>
```

Why does one have async and the other doesn't. I had at one point added the async to it but I've now removed it from the "header.php" file and I don't want it to have the async.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue was, I just deactivated and reactivated the theme.